# How to serialize a custom object from a class to a byte array for photon onserializeview and back to class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have read and re-read the [serializing custom types](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-US/realtime/current/reference/serialization-in-photon) portion of the Photon.

I prefer the 1st method because my original build makes that easier.

I have a player variable on the script in my game object that contains all of the important abstract objects and if I have to rebuild my  abstract objects to compensate for photons api I will but that will be awful.

Context

**abstract objects**

- abstract_player_actions
- abstract_player_animations
- abstract_player_interactions

**all instantiated in**

- abstract_player;

Then my npc, and my human player perform all those functions with the difference being where the inputs come from.

So my npc has npc_controller, my human player has hpc_controller and those instantiate the abstract player which in turn instantiates the other abstract objects.

```
player = new abstract_player()
```

There is a lot of code so I will try to put only the relevant parts.

I am getting a publickey=null is not marked as serializable; I Googled that and it said that I can't inherit from monobehavior and I should add [System.serializable] to the class.

None of my abstract objects inherit from monobehavior at all and all of them have the serializable tag.

My serialize and deserialize are

```
    public static byte[] serialize(object player)
    {
        MemoryStream mem_stream;
        BinaryFormatter formatter;

        formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        mem_stream = new MemoryStream();

        formatter.Serialize(mem_stream, player);

        return mem_stream.ToArray();


    }

    public static object deserialize(byte[] player_data)
    {
        MemoryStream mem_stream;
        BinaryFormatter formatter;

        formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        mem_stream = new MemoryStream(player_data);

        return formatter.Deserialize(mem_stream);


    }
```

I write this

```
public abstract_player(GameObject _player) {


        bool registered = PhotonPeer.RegisterType(
                            typeof(abstract_player), 
                            (byte)'a', 
                            serialize, 
                            deserialize);
}
```

There there is more in my constructor but as far as I can tell that is the relevant information in my constructor.

And then in my hpc_controller:

```
public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
{

    if (stream.IsWriting)
    {
        stream.SendNext(gameObject.name);

        stream.SendNext( player);
    }
    else if (stream.IsReading)
    {

        gameObject.name = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();

        player = (abstract_player) stream.ReceiveNext();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until I try to onserializeview with abstract player

The more testing I do the more I believe it is actually the conversion from object to byte array, but everything I see tells me I'm doing it right.

### Edit

To add clarity here is my constructor for abstract_player()

```
    public abstract_player(GameObject _player) {

        is_currently_stealing_from_cart = false;

        this.player = _player;

        set_characters_hand();

        actions = new abstract_player_actions(this.player);

        change_players_name(UnityEngine.Random.RandomRange(0, 100));

        animations = new abstract_player_animations(this.player);

        camera_position = this.player.transform.Find("Camera position").gameObject;

        // send the ui to the player
        interactions = new abstract_player_interactions(GameObject.Find("UI Manager").GetComponent<ui_controller>());

        this.interactions.ui.cart_status_button.onClick.AddListener(() => change_cart_status());

        this.interactions.ui.grab_merchandise_button.onClick.AddListener(() => grab_the_merchandise());

        this.interactions.ui.steal_from_cart_button.onClick.AddListener(() => display_cart_inventory());

        this.look_at_target = this.player.transform.Find("Look at target").gameObject;

        set_characters_hand();


        /// this is where the cart is created and attached to the hand to start with
        generate_correct_cart(cart_type: "pushcart");

        actions.make_the_player_grab_or_release_the_cart(
                                         enumerations.cart_posession.grab,
                                         correct_cart: this.current_cart,
                                         players_hand: this.players_hand
                                         );

        

        set_cart_position_and_orientation_variables();

        position_cart();

        /// give the player the cart and act from actions
        actions.has_cart = true;

        // send the actions variable to the animations function
        animations.set_animator_has_cart_variable(has_cart: actions.has_cart);

        interactions.show_cart_status_button();

        should_show_aisle_info = false;

        has_merchandise_in_hand = false;

        set_throw_predictor();

        set_throw_predictor_details();

        this.victim_cart = null;

        bool registered = PhotonPeer.RegisterType(typeof(abstract_player), (byte)'a', serialize, deserialize);

    }
```

Comment: Just a general note for readability: You should stick to the commonly used coding convention in c# of having class names in [PascalCase](https://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase) and without underscores. The same also for method names.

Comment: Also when saying `all inherited by abstract_player;` do you mean they all inherit **from** `abstract_player`? .. because a class can only inherit from exactly one parent class ...

Comment: im writing this myself and i like _ better and what i mean by all inherited by abstract_player i mean exactly what i say   --- inside the constructor of abstract_player() -- is actions = new abtract_player_actions(); animations = new abtract_player_animations();  and interactions = new abtract_player_interactions()

Comment: Well what you say makes no sense ... if you say they are all three inherited **by** `abstract_player` it would mean that `abstract_player` implements members of all three classes .. which is not possible in `c#` (or object oriented programming in general!). What you mean and should say is: They all inherit **from** `abstract_player` ....

Comment: Please add your class implementations,. Your last comment sounds like all three types are fields within `abstract_player`? Are these types serializable?

Comment: okay then i dont want to get lost interms let me just edit the post and put the whole construtor infor abstract player so you can see

Comment: i can do that but its alot of code and yes they are all serializable

Comment: I would be more interested in the things you want to serialize ;) meaning the fields of the classes (the constructor itself doesn't really matter here as methods etc are not serialized but class fields)

Comment: Should I mark each individual field as serialisable?

Comment: You need to mark the according classes/structs as `[Serializable]`. For getting serialized the fields do either have to be `public` or be tagged `[SerializeField]`.

Comment: Ok I will look at that thanks

 I assumed serialising the class would also serialize the subsequent values inside 

Thanks

Comment: (Aside: questions featuring all-lower-case writing and material that has not been spell-checked may attract downvotes).

Comment: i did try to add the serializable tag to the individual fields and that didn't help. Im still reading to see what nuance or big thing i missed but any recommendations are appreciated

Comment: i am reading the link again and noticing photon in their serializing function did so with each individual element. i have alot more vars but i am trying to turn each one into a byte array indiviually its going to take some time so i will let you know how it goes